# Write code to print all numbers from 1 to `num` JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I'm given a problem to "Write code to print all (whole) numbers from 1 to `num`(argument inclusive) in JavaScript
(Assume `num` will be a positive number) (e.g if num=4 it should print 1,2,3,4)
Could anyone help please.

```
    var logNums = function(num) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `for` loop will come to your help:

```
function printNumbers(num) {

    if (num < 1) {
        console.error('num must be greater than 1');
        return;
    }

    if (!Number.isInteger(num)) {
        num = Math.trunc(num);
    }

    for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        console.info(i);
    }
}

printNumbers(10);
```

Comment: Yes Mark C. That was my homework and I'm a beginner. I spent a couple of hours to solve it and actually came to the for loop function but still couldn't past the test. Then I added "console.log(i)" in as Babak showed then it worked. So could anyone tell me what exactly "console.log(i)" did to make the function work?

Comment: The console.log() method simply writes a message to the console. Probably what you missed was just displaying outputs, i.e. numbers.

Answer (score 0):

this would work:

```
var logNums = function(num) {

  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {        
  console.log(i);
  }

};
```